# Mocking a function inside a function in Python Unit Testing using Mock

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am using Mock for Python Unit Testing. I am testing a function `foo` which contains a function `bar` that doesn't return anything, but fills a variable `x` (type:io.StringIO) as a side effect. I have mocked `bar` using MagicMock, but I don't know how to assign to `x` from a test script.

I have the following situation:

```
def foo():
    x = io.StringIO()
    bar(x)                 # x is filled with some string by bar method
    here some operation on x
```

To write a Unit Test case for `foo`, I have mocked `bar` with MagicMock (return value=None) but how to assign to `x` which is needed by `foo`.

Comment: Can you be more clearer of what you want?

Comment: Is the variable passed to the nested function, or is it just relying on the closure?

Answer (score 4):

You need to mock `io.StringIO` and you can then replace it with something else:

```
@mock.patch('mymodule.io.StringIO')
def test_foo(self, mock_stringio):
    mock_stringio.return_value = mock.Mock()
```

Note the use of `return_value` which means you're mocking the instance that's returned from the `StringIO()` call.